# Detect end of PDF document

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Is there a way in Adobe Acrobat to detect if a user is on the last page?  What I would like to do is set some document javascript to trigger once they are on the last page.  I know how to setup the document javascript in Acrobat, just haven't found any way to detect what page its on.  Ideally it would be nice to be able to get the current page and page count and compare, but even if there is a current page variable, I could just hard code the last page.  My fallback will be to add a button or checkbox on the last page, but would like to avoid that.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages have actions just like fields do, so in your case, you could use the last page's Open event to trigger your Javascript.

To set a page action, open the "Page Thumbnails" navigation pane on the left, right click the page, then add an action as you would to a field. Alternatively, a page action can be set via Javascript. In your case this would look something like `this.setPageAction(this.numPages-1, "Open", action);`

Comment: I couldn't find an answer without having to do some coding on the last page directly in a PDF, so I marked this as the correct answer.